# How to return status code 418 in Webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

It seems Webapp2 does not support the status code `418` because it doesn't have a status message mapped to it. How do I get around it and return a `418`?

```
response.set_status(418)    # does not work
response.status_int = 418   # does not work either
```

Traceback:

```
  File "/.../App Engine SDK/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 425, in set_status
    self.status = code
  File "/.../App Engine SDK/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 405, in _set_status
    message = message or Response.http_status_message(code)
  File "/.../App Engine SDK/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 488, in http_status_message
    raise KeyError('Invalid HTTP status code: %d' % code)
KeyError: 'Invalid HTTP status code: 418'
```

Comment: I'm intrigued as to what the use case is....

Comment: http://save418.com/

Comment: @Kai The server should return `418` when someone is trying to brew coffee with a teapot ;)

Comment: Doesn't it work? What happens? Looking at the source code it seems like it uses WebOb, which *does* include 418: https://github.com/Pylons/webob/blob/master/src/webob/util.py#L103

Comment: @jonrsharpe Added traceback. Edit: Looking inside `statusreasons.py` in the App Engine SDK, `418` is indeed missing.

Comment: It looks like you have a different version than the one currently on GitHub, which would throw from a different line: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/webapp2/blob/master/webapp2.py#L525. As far as I can see the current version using latest WebOb wouldn't throw that error. Which versions are you running?

Comment: App Engine SDK 1.9.40. It's probably not the latest version since I haven't updated it in quite a while.

Comment: So based on the fact that it's using `statusreasons.py` it seems it's pre-1.0 WebOb: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/webapp2/blob/master/webapp2.py#L53. Looks like you'll have to upgrade or patch to get 418.

Comment: How do I go about updating the SDK? Are there any convenient bash commands that I can use to update it?

Comment: The `418` code is available in `webob-1.2.3`, present in the SDK since at least `1.9.30`, but requesting it in the `app.yaml` file doesn't appear to help, `webapp2-2.5.2` keeps using `webob_0_9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By monkey patching, I am able to get the status code **418** to work, but only partially.

```
class TeapotHandle(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        from webob import util
        import httplib

        util.status_reasons[418] = "I'm a teapot"
        httplib.responses[418] = "I'm a teapot"

        self.response.set_status(418)
```

yields, using the *dev server*:

```
HTTP/1.1 418 Unknown Status Code
[...]
```

But in fact, it works as expected once deployed on App Engine Cloud:

```
HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a Teapot
[...]
```